# Debug the StackOverFlow exception

Tags: c#, debugging

When I run my C# program it throws an Stack Overflow exception in one of the methods on a DLL that I have a reference to it in my solution.
but no debugging info is available to me because it says it is an stack overflow exception and no info is available.
what are the next debugging steps that I should follow to understand what is going on and why ?

thanks

**Edit**: here is the code that stops at:

```
static public Collection SortCollection(Collection oCollection, string sPropertyName, string sKeyPropertyName)
{ 
    return SortCollection(oCollection, sPropertyName, sKeyPropertyName); 
}
```

Comment: sure, here is the code that stops at:
static public Collection SortCollection(Collection oCollection, string sPropertyName, string sKeyPropertyName)
{
     return SortCollection(oCollection, sPropertyName, sKeyPropertyName);
}

Comment: @BDotA you have an infinite recursion. function calls itself without any restriction!

Comment: Yikes, that is correct.  A VB to C# converter tool has converted tons on our code and it looks like we need to fix a lot of issue in the generated code like this one. thanks all.

Comment: To be honest, unconditional recursion should like that should stick out like a sore thumb!

Comment: I think he/she just wanted to post a question with StackOverflow in the title ;p

Comment: Ok, I studied the code more carefully, The problem is that we had wanted to have method Overloads for this SortCollection method to use optional parameters, etc. so this one is a bad overload since its signature is exactly the same as the original method that handles all the overloads causing to call its self again and again instead of calling the correct method.

Comment: The reason you're getting StackOverflowException when converting from C# to VB is because VB is not case sensitive. In C#, developers often have private references that are lowercase, and accessors that are upper case. When converted to VB, VB reads them both the same, and when returning an object like in your example, or as part of a Get, it gets confused and accesses itself, causing an infinite loop. The key is never to use variables that only differ by case in projects that will have both VB and C# versions.

Comment: When using code tools to convert, you may not notice, because VB will remove the difference in casing when it is loaded, making it harder to spot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 99% cases root cause is infinite recursion.

Comment: Well, yeah, but I think the point of his question is that he needs to find out *where* or *why* the infinite recursion is happening.  This is a little bit like saying that an `OutOfMemoryException` means you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code, the method SortCollection just keeps calling itself over and over.  That will create an infinite loop.

You need to do something inside the function to make it eventually stop calling itself, like Andrey says in his comment.

Comment: correct, the problem was that it has a been an Overload version of a bigger method but since the parameters are the same it is calling itself instead of calling the correct version

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading .NET Reflector Pro.  .NET Reflector (the base product) allows you to "decompile" .NET assemblies, giving you the ability to view the source code.

.NET Reflector Pro takes it one step further and allows you to debug through the source code of any arbitrary .NET assembly.

Pro is not free, but there is a short trial period.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: yea, it is good tool, I have its pro version. but in this case that DLL is ours, so I have its source code and can attahc it to my solution file to compile it.